# Trouble customizing profile in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to make a minor customization to profile information in ASP.NET Identity by following the example on this [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) page and the Identity 2.0 Sample Project from

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
```

Rather than adding a simple DateTime BirthDate field, I am trying to add a simple custom field called 'Region'  (to be picked from a set list of sales regions)

I created a new class called Region inside of IdentityModels.cs

```
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Region()
    {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

I then added the class as a property to the ApplicationUser class in place of the BirthDate property in the example. Like so:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Region Region { get; set; }
```

I then rebuild without error and run add-migration and update-database like so:

```
PM> add-migration "Region"
Scaffolding migration 'Region'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Region' again.
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201409280314023_Region].
Applying explicit migration: 201409280314023_Region.
Running Seed method.
```

The database is created and the Region table is there, but; When I attempt to enter 'context.Regions.AddOrUpdate' to the Seed method, 'Regions' is not an allowable member of context. (I would like to pre-load the table with a list of regions)

```
protected override void Seed(SentinelPortal.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(   //this is OK

                r => r.Name,
                new IdentityRole() { Name = "Admin"},
                new IdentityRole() { Name = "RegionAdmin"},
                new IdentityRole() { Name = "User"}
            );

            context.Regions.AddOrUpdate(   //This indicates that Regions doesn't exist in 'context'
               r => r.Name,
               new Region() { Name = "NW" },
               new Region() { Name = "SW" }
            );
        }
```

So my question is: Why is Regions not part of 'context' even tho the table is being created in the db?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The answer turned out to be that I needed to add this to the ApplicationDbContect class

```
 public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
```